# Two different colors for input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to achieve the output as like below image

[image]

Black color text is name and Orange color text is status. Depending on status it can change like Pending --> Orange, Completed-->Green. These things I can able to achieve  by having one `input` tag and `span` tag inside a `div` which position is relative

```
<div style="display: inline-block;position: relative;overflow: hidden;width:100%">

                <input
                id="input"
                class={computedInputClass}
                type="text"
                role="textbox"
                required={required}
                autocomplete="off"
                value={computedInputValue}
                name={name}/>

                <span class={computedStatusClass} style={componentStyle}> - {inputStatus}</span>
</div>
```

The only problem what I am facing is placing the position of status text.

Depending on the length of name text the left of status text also has to be adjusted. I am doing left adjustment with this calculation but its not working

```
 get componentStyle() {  
       // this.computedInputValue = 'William Thomas';
        return `left:${this.computedInputValue.length-2}em`;
    }
```

If my approach is wrong please suggest me for good solution but for sure I have to use `<input>` tag and I cant remove that also as it is LWC component

Here is what I tried

### HTML

```
<template>
  <div style="display: inline-block;position: relative;overflow: hidden;width:100%">
                <input
                id="input"
                class={computedInputClass}
                type="text"
                role="textbox"              
                autocomplete="off"
                value={computedInputValue}
               
            />
                <span class={computedStatusClass} style={componentStyle}> - {inputStatus}</span>
            </div>
</template>
```

### JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track inputStatus='Pending';

     get computedInputValue() {
        return 'William ThomasS';
    }
     
    get componentStyle() {         
        return `left:${this.computedInputValue.length-2}em`;
    }

    get computedStatusClass()
    {
     return 'customizedDropdownInputStatusLeft customizedDropdownPendingStatusColor';     
    }

     get computedInputClass() {
       
        return'slds-input';
    }
}
```

### CSS

```
.customizedDropdownInputStatusLeft{
    position: absolute;   
    top:8px
}
.customizedDropdownPendingStatusColor{
    color:orange;
}
.customizedDropdownStatusPadding{
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put both the name and the 'status' in the same component? That way the name automatically adjusts the status

Comment: I tried like that but i cant able to achieve the color(Orange or green)

Comment: If you [create a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/home) I will fix it for you. The code snippets you have provided are incomplete.

Comment: @AlexMckay, Since its LWC component thought of to create a playground in Salesforce site but unfortunately salesforce playground is not working today [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground). Can i add the files here?

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner Show what you tried

Comment: Does `ComponentStyle` return the correct color? (orange or red)

Comment: @AlexMckay ,AksJacoves :I have edited my question and added whole HTML,JS and CSS I tried

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner did the answer I provided below work for you?

Comment: @AlexMckay Thank you .Working perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve your desired result with the following code.

The key part is a hidden span element and a `resizeUserInput` function:

`hiddenSpan.textContent = userInput.value` - copy the input text into the hidden span element.

`userInput.style.width = hiddenSpan.offsetWidth + px` - get the width of the hidden element and apply it to the width of the user input.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-question-75tyd)

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="box">
    <p>
      <span class="hidden-span" id="hidden-span"></span>
            <input class='user-input' id="user-input" type="text" value="William Thomas" />
      <span> - </span>
      <span class="status">Pending</span>
        </p>
        <div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
body,
input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hidden-span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}

.user-input {
  border: none;
  min-width: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.status {
  color: orange;
}
```

**JS**

```js
const px = "px";

const hiddenSpan = document.getElementById("hidden-span");
const userInput = document.getElementById("user-input");

const resizeUserInput = () => {
  hiddenSpan.textContent = userInput.value;
  userInput.style.width = hiddenSpan.offsetWidth + px;
};

resizeUserInput() // run onload
userInput.addEventListener("input", resizeUserInput); // run on subsequent changes
```